# Power management on a Dell R620 with iDrac7

Tags: dell, drac

I have set up a Dell R620 with iDRAC7 Enterprise - where I have bonded LOM1 and LOM2, and connected them to two different switches for failover.

When the server is powered on, I can access the idrac and do power cycle, read power status, but when I reboot the server, I can't access the idrac with racadm og ipmitools (CentOS).

Do I have to use the dedicated NIC on the idrac7 for power management when the server is powered off?

Comment: it is generally preferred to use the dedicated port in general if/when you can. Try the dedicated port and see if that works.

Comment: Yes, I understand that - I'll just try to avoid it for easier setup and cable/switch-management.

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from Dell Support on this.

It is normal that one cannot access the iDRAC for some period during reboot, because the "NICs must also reboot during a reboot"

http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/extras/m/white_papers/20060878

A poweron / powercycle when the server is down is supported if the switch is configured to support Wake-On-LAN.